# I'm confusing with the Google sign in instruction. [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID Where I type that?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following the steps for the Google sign in implementation, but I don't know where I type this row of code:

[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;

The instruction say this:

Also, you will need to set the client ID directly using the value found in the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Link of page: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It recommends putting that line of code in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: inside your AppDelegate.

Replace kClientID with the ClientID that is found in the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Make sure you import the needed Google Files as well.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend!

Comment: How will we paste it? I get error when I paste the one found in the plist